# Normalisation : Some advice please

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, normalization

I have a `DF` that looks as follows:

```
       ECON1     ECON2     ECON3     FOOD1     FOOD2     FOOD3      ENV1  \
28  0.310071  0.096913  0.228500  0.234986  0.260894  0.267858  0.489309   
28  0.353609  0.045075  0.222571  0.222803  0.248388  0.330560  0.060107   
28  0.280600  0.170201  0.232027  0.226792  0.233379  0.316765  0.114550   
28  0.299062  0.127866  0.198080  0.189948  0.222982  0.327082  0.052881   

        ENV2      HEA1      HEA2      HEA3     PERS1     PERS2     PERS3  \
28  0.206320  0.252537  0.266968  0.248452  0.184450  0.093345  0.173952   
28 -0.206570  0.263673  0.126182  0.265908  0.134481  0.191341  0.113324   
28  0.237818  0.257337  0.102037  0.214423  0.159002  0.321451  0.165960   
28  0.345857  0.272412  0.069192  0.251301  0.130606  0.132732  0.174925   

        COM1      COM2      POL1      POL2  
28  0.781430  0.487822  0.361886  0.233124  
28  0.083918  0.005381  0.266604  0.237078  
28  0.395897  0.257888  0.330607  0.229079  
28  0.000000  0.000000  0.307907  0.238908
```

This `DF` is the result of a normalisation as follows:

```
DF.apply(lambda x: x / np.linalg.norm(x), axis=0)
```

My issue is that this type of normalisation does not guarantee non-negative values. I could have used:

```
DF.apply(lambda x: (x - x.min() )/ (x.max() - x.min()), axis=0)
```

But the issue here is that I get columns with all `zeros` or all `ones`. When you try to work with those values (to do factor analysis or correlation analysis) they appear as constant when they are not, these are just the results of a normalisation process.

Is there is a way to normalise while guaranting the positivity and variability of the data?

Answer (score 0):

If all values are equal (all zeros, all ones, or all whatever) the division will be necessarily by 0 (becase the `value.max() - value.min()`), which raises an error in Python by default. However, Pandas returns `NaN` instead of raising such erros. So you can easily fill up these values with `0` if it makes sense to you:

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x - x.min())/ (x.max() - x.min()), axis=0).fillna(0.0)
```

It's equivalent of using the [`preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html):

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
pd.DataFrame(min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df))
```

Comment: Dear Caina. Thank you. The DF is the result of the normalisation. I am not looking to normalise DF, it is already normalised. I am looking to find a different way to normalise